# SOAP atomic transaction on WebLogic call can not find transaction coordinator

Tags: java, web-services, soap, weblogic, transactional

**Intro**
I am trying to test behavior of WebCenter Content SOAP Services (GenericSOAP) in an atomic transaction.
Installed products are (from installations available on Oracle pages, version: 12.2.1.3.0):

- WebLogic
- WebCenter Content

SOAP client is a simple web application deployed on the WebLogic consisting of:

- html page with only a link which calls a servlet
- servlet which calls a service class
- service class with a SOAP client

**Short description of a problem**
When calling GenericSOAP in atomic transaction I get an error:

```
Error while invoking endpoint http://<host>:7001/wls-wsat/RegistrationPortTypeRPC from client
```

Note: `<host`> is an actual IP address of the host, I just replaced it with word `<host`> manually above and in the log below.

**More details**
After installation of WebLogic and WebCenter Content, by using Enterprise Manager I modified policies on the GenericSOAP Web Service:

- removed "oracle/wsmtom_policy"
- added "oracle/no_mtom_policy" (SOAP call as an anonymous user works)
- added "oracle/wss_username_token_service_policy" for simple authentication test (SOAP call as an user works)
- added "oracle/atomic_transaction_policy" for atomic transaction (SOAP call works depending on client configuration)

If I make a SOAP call without any modifications to enable transactional call (same call that was used to test "oracle/wss_username_token_service_policy"), SOAP call works.
If I register client as transactional with following annotation

```
@weblogic.wsee.wstx.wsat.Transactional(
   version = weblogic.wsee.wstx.wsat.Transactional.Version.DEFAULT,
   value = weblogic.wsee.wstx.wsat.Transactional.TransactionFlowType.SUPPORTS
)
```

SOAP call doesn't work and I get the error stated at the beginning of this question.
By removing above annotation, SOAP call works again. By adding it back, SOAP call doesn't work.

When logging the SOAP request/response, in the request there is CoordinationContext with the above address.

Log from the UCM_server1-diagnostic.log is:

```
[UCM_server1] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.wsm.security.policy.scenario.util.ScenarioUtils] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: <anonymous>] [ecid: e2b32686-5fe2-49d6-bdb4-1238c80399ad-00004c16,0:2] [APP: Oracle UCM Web Services] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL] [J2EE_APP.name: Oracle UCM Web Services] [J2EE_MODULE.name: idcws.war] [WEBSERVICE.name: GenericSoapService] [WEBSERVICE_PORT.name: GenericSoapPort] [oracle.wsm.policy.name: oracle/wss_username_token_service_policy] User name from authenticated subject: ranko

[UCM_server1] [ERROR] [] [] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: <anonymous>] [ecid: e2b32686-5fe2-49d6-bdb4-1238c80399ad-00004c16,0:2] [APP: Oracle UCM Web Services] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL] [J2EE_APP.name: Oracle UCM Web Services] [J2EE_MODULE.name: idcws.war] [WEBSERVICE.name: GenericSoapService] [WEBSERVICE_PORT.name: GenericSoapPort] Error while invoking endpoint http://<host>:7001/wls-wsat/RegistrationPortTypeRPC from client; ServiceName: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/10/wscoor}RegistrationService_V10 ; PortName: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/10/wscoor}RegistrationCoordinatorPortTypePort ; Client side features: [weblogic.jws.jaxws.client.ClientIdentityFeature][com.sun.xml.ws.developer.MemberSubmissionAddressingFeature][com.sun.xml.ws.api.addressing.OneWayFeature]; Client side policies: 

[UCM_server1] [ERROR] [] [oracle.webservices.service] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: <anonymous>] [ecid: e2b32686-5fe2-49d6-bdb4-1238c80399ad-00004c16,0:2] [APP: Oracle UCM Web Services] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL] An error occurred for port: {urn:GenericSoap}GenericSoapPort: oracle.fabric.common.PolicyEnforcementException: The server sent HTTP status code 404: Not Found.
```

To make the call as simple as I can, I am calling "DOC_INFO_BY_NAME" since it takes only one parameter and can be executed as anonymous user.

**From additional research:**

- it seems that it fails when it tries to register the service with the transaction coordinator
- there is no need to have SOA installed for the ws-xt to work, WebLogic is enough
- in the JTA part of the WebLogic Console coordinator can be configured, but only the part if I want to secure the messages exchanged. Which I don't need for testing purposes. From what I can see there is no "enable/disable" coordinator, port number, etc.
- Configuration of SOAP endpoints for transaction as explained in the documentation (through WebLogic Console) doesn't work. GenericSOAP service/endpoints are not exposed/visible there.
- Configuration of GenericSOAP endpoint in Enterprise Manager has following values (out of the box):

  - Atomic Transaction Flow Option: Supports
  - Atomic Transaction Version: Default

It looks like a “simple case" where coordinator is not working and should be turned on/installed but, from what I have managed to find, it should be available/working out of the box on the “plain” WebLogic.

Thank you for your time and kind regards,
Ranko

Answer (score 0):

Weblogic 12c needs to have the WS-AT enabled manually, since this is disabled by default:

```
readDomain('domain')
create('ofs','OptionalFeatureDeployment')
cd('OptionalFeatureDeployment/ofs')
create('WSAT', 'OptionalFeature') cd('OptionalFeature/WSAT')
set('Enabled',true)  
updateDomain()
closeDomain()
exit()
```

For details see:
see:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/weblogic-server/12.2.1.4/wsget/jax-ws-atomictransaction.html#GUID-25C8E673-73A2-4596-8291-A7C351B5BB33